# mysql for excel

Tags: mysql, excel, export-to-excel, mysql-workbench, excel-2013

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question but I am facing an issue with MySQL installed failing to recognize office 2013 and install MySQL for Excel.

Basically MySQL
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Has an addin for excel that allows you to automatically connect to a database and make changes. During the MySQL installation it checks for requirements, one of which is Excel 2007 or greater. And that requirement is not met for me. 
I am running Office 2013 Pro Plus (64bit) and Installing MySQL (64bit)

Can someone help? Is there any other application that you recommend?
I dont want to import and export data or files manually. 
I need an application that opens all the tables in separate sheets that I can manually change and automatically save to the DB.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a [known bug](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?172,578515,578629#msg-578629):

> For now please try the following workaround:
>
> 1. Launch the MySQL Installer (if already installed launch it from Start Menu > MySQL > MySQL Installer).
> 2. Try to do a Full Installation (but you do not have to actually install them).
> 3. Go to C:\Program Data\MySQL\MySQL Installer\Product Cache
> 4. See if you have there the MySQL for Excel MSI and launch it manually.

I would look these other topics on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+office+2013).

Comment: Yeah, I googled it too, no luck. No MySQL for Excel in there.

Comment: I also tried to extract the msi installer and found the installation file but I don't know how to execute it. Cant tell what file format it is.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is fixed as of MySQL for Excel 1.2.1. However, due to the nature of this bug, you must manually uninstall previous versions of MySQL for Excel before installing v1.2.1+.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. You can download the `mysql_for_excel` standalone `.msi` file here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/excel/

After that copy the .msi to `C:\Program Data\MySQL\MySQL Installer\Product Cache`
and execute it. Restart the excel. Done

Then in the Data tab you can see this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem in Mysql 8.0.17 and the Mysql for excel not showing in the data tab, after install and uninstall several time finally found the problem in the adds-in for user of my windows. You must open the excel app by [open as administrator] Mysql for excel appeared after this.